# Is there a word that means "over-enunciate the k sound"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation, phonetics

I am trying to say the word ***week*** but focus on the ***k*** sound at the end and really emphasize it. I tend to do this naturally in my everyday speech. It kinda sounds like an odd throat sound when I do it. Is there a name for this?

Comment: Just for 'k' or for any sound at the end of a word or for any sound whatsoever?

Answer (score 5):

At a guess (and without a recording it can be no more than that), you are doing one of two things:

- If you are merely "overarticulating" the /k/, like an anxious student in a voice production class, you are probably producing a little puff of air when you release the consonant. This sounds like the "BrE" recording on [this](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/week) page, and in IPA it is notated thus: /kʰ/. This is called [*aspiration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant); in English it is usually heard only when /k/ starts a syllable and is followed by a vowel, not at the end of a word or before another consonant.

  (An unanspirated /k/ before a vowel is often heard among Indian speakers of English; in many subcontinental languages both aspirated and unaspirated stops may appear in this position, and the difference is meaningful.)
- If you are really pushing the /k/ it is possible that there is a stretch of time after the release when the tongue is still very close to the palate and air 'hisses' between them. If this is the case you are producing a sound which is not a part of the English phonemic repertory, a [*voiceless palatal fricative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_fricative). This is notated /ç/ and is heard in, for instance, German *ich*, which you may listen to on [this](http://www.forvo.com/word/ich/) page. (Ignore the pronunciation there by Nilreb.)

Comment: Here I always the word for over enunciating the final /k/ was *cough*. :)

Comment: Another possibility is glottalization; I tend to glottalize word-final voiceless plosives ([ˈwiʔkʰ]).

Comment: Yes, I sound like the recording you posted but I overarticulate the /k/ even more. Thanks for the information and terminology.